# Android - Good practise for retaining a singleton in multi activity application

Tags: android, singleton

Sometimes the application is destroyed and I may have some temporary values in a singleton. Android restores my activities but not my singleton. So my solution for this is to save the singleton in ALL activities and restore it whenever an activity is recreated and the singleton does not exist anymore.

This seems like not being a good solution as I very often save the singleton for nothing. The application does not have and function that's called before it is destroyed so I can't use this either.

What's a good practise to have a singleton in android that's save to application terminations?

*EDIT*

My solution is following:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Global.restore(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Global.save(outState);
    }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Global implements Parcelable {

    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE = "GLOBAL";

    private static Global INSTANCE = null;

    public static synchronized Global get() 
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new Global();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static synchronized void save(Bundle outState)
    {
        // save the singleton... not very effective, is happening on every's activity destroy
        if (INSTANCE != null)
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_BUNDLE, INSTANCE);
    }

    public static synchronized void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // ONLY read it if it does not already exists
        if (INSTANCE != null)
            return;

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE))
            INSTANCE = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_BUNDLE);
    }

    // Data and Parcelable code...
    // ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences to save data.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I added code to show my current solution. I don't want to slow that down by writing to a file. And I don't see any improvement in using `SharedPreferences`... It's slower and I have to manually clear it if the app is finished on purpose and get's destroyued afterwards. If the user leaves the app with backpress and no active activity is left and therefore no activity restores the singleton, my solution won't do anything, the singleton will be started in a clear state again...